# 301 htaccess redirect doesn't work without a slash

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect some of an old website page to it's noew version on a new domain like that in an `htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage https://new.domain/newpage
```

If I enter https://**old**.domain/**old**page**/** in my browser I'm redirected correctly (to https://**new**.domain/**new**page)

However if I enter https://**old**.domain/**old**page (without the last slash) I'm redirected to https://**new**.domain/**old**page

What's the probem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess Redirect 301 with trailing slash adds trailing slash to destination](https://serverfault.com/questions/1037305/htaccess-redirect-301-with-trailing-slash-adds-trailing-slash-to-destination)

Comment: The directive you posted won't result in either of the two examples you posted, so either "something else" is performing those redirects, or you are seeing a cached response. Bear in mind that if you have been experimenting with 301 (permanent) redirects then these will get cached persistently by the browser.